# "Missing right parenthesis" error while using Sub-Query with INNER JOIN in Oracle

Tags: oracle, subquery, inner-join

I have a Oracle command as

```
Select offers.OFR_STAT,OFFER_DETAILS.*,PrevData.*
From offers
INNER JOIN OFFER_DETAILS
    ON OFFER_DETAILS.OFFER_ID=offers.OFFER_ID
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT InnerOfrDtl.*
    FROM OFFER_DETAILS as InnerOfrDtl 
    WHERE InnerOfrDtl.offer_id=offers.offer_id
) AS PrevData
    ON PrevData.SCHEDULE_TYPE=OFFER_DETAILS.SCHEDULE_TYPE
```

While running I got an error message as "missing right parenthesis".
Here I wanted to use a sub-query for Inner join.

Comment: Why do you want to use the sub-query?  The query shown would work OK without a sub-query.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the AS after the close parenthesis and before `PrevData`.  As I understand it, Oracle does not allow the keyword AS for table aliases.

---

The query does not require a sub-query.  You could write:

```
SELECT o.OFR_STAT, d.*, p.*
  FROM offers o
  JOIN Offer_Details d ON d.Offer_ID = o.Offer_ID
  JOIN Offer_Details p
    ON p.Offer_ID = o.Offer_ID
   AND p.Schedule_Type = d.Schedule_Type
```

I'm not wholly convinced that the query makes sense, but that's a different matter altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `AS` keyword for the sub-query, this is not supported by Oracle:

```
Select offers.OFR_STAT,OFFER_DETAILS.*,PrevData.*
From offers
INNER JOIN OFFER_DETAILS
    ON OFFER_DETAILS.OFFER_ID=offers.OFFER_ID
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT InnerOfrDtl.*
    FROM OFFER_DETAILS as InnerOfrDtl 
    WHERE InnerOfrDtl.offer_id=offers.offer_id
) PrevData  -- <<<< here is the change
    ON PrevData.SCHEDULE_TYPE=OFFER_DETAILS.SCHEDULE_TYPE
```

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of Oracle (8i for sure, probably 9i too) have trouble with explicit INNER JOINs.  Replacing them with implicit (non-ANSI?) inner joins can fix the problem.

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=328028